# How can I access to a child class instead of parent class in a 'callback' function of factorybot in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I have implemented a STI in ROR. please look at the following code:

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
end

class CourseCategory < Category
  has_many :courses
end
```

I use FactoryBot to create data like this:

```
# category

FactoryBot.define do
  factory :category do
    name {"Ruby on Rails"}
  end
end

# course_category

FactoryBot.define do
  factory :course_category, parent: :category, class: 'Category' do
    trait :with_course do
      after(:create) do |course_category| # my problem is here
      create :course, :with_steps, course_category: course_category
    end
  end
end

# course

FactoryBot.define do
  factory :course do
     course_category
  end
end
```

while I run `FactoryBot.create(:course_category, :with_course)`, into `trait :with_course` , I should have **CourseCategory** class, but I receive **Category**.

Can I have access to parent class instead of child class into a callback of FactoryBot?

Comment: I believe this is wrong: `factory :course_category, parent: :category, class: 'Category' do` it should be   `factory :course_category, parent: :category, class: 'CourseCategory' do`

Comment: It works :) thanks.
would you like to write this problem into an answer?
then I will mark it as the correct answer

Comment: Sure, happy to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your factory is building `:course_category` as the wrong class.

This line needs to be changed...

```
factory :course_category, parent: :category, class: 'Category' do
```

Into...

```
factory :course_category, parent: :category, class: 'CourseCategory' do
```